# Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user from javascript client

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using cloud endpoints with authentication on python environment.
And I have two registered apps, one is native, other is web, on Cloud Console.

In native app, I can use my apis after authentication. But in web app, below error is happened.

> Oauth framework user didn't match oauth token user.

The sequence is below:

1. I can get the result of gapi.auth.authorize() with token.
2. And when I call gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get(), I can get user info without error.
3. But when I call my api, I get this oauth error.

Of course I added client ids(native, web, api explorer) to allowed_client_ids.

But if the client id of web is removed, same error is happened and no warning about client id missing.
(As far as I know, If the client id in the request is not in allowed_client_ids, the warning about Client ID is not allowed is in the log)
And when I call api through the api explorer, same error is happened.

I don't have any idea how to investigate about this error with this short log message.
Is there any check points, suggestions?

Sorry for my poor English.
thanks,

**UPDATE:**

After some investigations, I've got root cause, it's Authentication Type of the application.
The Authentication Type of my application is Google Apps domain.
I created another application with Google Account API authentication type and deployed same code,
I can get user info from get_current_user().

In the document, Cloud Endpoints project is created through Cloud Console,
but my application is created through AppEngine Console before.

thanks,

Comment: To help anybody else that might end up here - I fixed the same error (just not using the JS client) with two things: 1. Change App Engine's Google Authentication setting to "Google Accounts API", not "Google Apps Domain", and 2. Use the HTTP header 'Authorization: Bearer <access token here>" instead of the "?access_token=<access token here>" query string parameter.